# Passing an array of images from tableview to collectionview

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview, tableview

I have to view controllers. First, a table view and second a collection view in a second detail view. I created an array of arrays of images. I expect to click in the cell table and pass one array of images to the collection view. I defined a file model with the array of arrays. I defined two more controllers for cell table and cell collection views as well.

Problem: I can not pass this array of array images. I did pass an array of strings to a textview in the detail using prepare for segue. Volk there, I will really appreciate your help. Can take a look to the project in GitHub: https://github.com/ricardovaldes/hotelesWithIos9

At the moment, when I click the table cell I obtain some pictures of different arrays, and no matter which cell I click, always the same pictures.

```
import UIKit

class DetailVCViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let hotel = Hotel()
    var myDescription = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var myCollection: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var hotelDescription: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        hotelDescription.text = myDescription
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hotel.array.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = myCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCellCollectionViewCell

        cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: hotel.array[indexPath.row][indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func reservar(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }


}


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

    let hotel = Hotel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let cell = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        myTable.register(cell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableCell")

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hotel.hotelNames.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.hotelName.text = hotel.hotelNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.hotelImage.image = UIImage(named: hotel.hotelImages[indexPath.row])
        cell.hotelImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return cell

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 250
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let index = myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let indexNumber = index?.row
        let secondVC = segue.destination as! DetailVCViewController
        secondVC.myDescription = hotel.description[indexNumber!]

    }

}
```

Comment: Some code from the table and detail:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DetailVCViewController`, you are creating a new object of `Hotel`, so this object is not the same object that you selected in the `TableView` `cell` in `ViewController`. Replace `hotel` object to an `array of String` as below so that you can pass the array from the selected `TabelView` cell index to `DetailVCViewController`

```
class DetailVCViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var array: [String] = []
    var myDescription = ""
    ....
}
```

Now in `ViewController`, update the `prepare(for segue:` as below to pass the array

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

   ....

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      let index = myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow
      let indexNumber = index?.row
      let secondVC = segue.destination as! DetailVCViewController 
      secondVC.myDescription = hotel.description[indexNumber!]
      secondVC.array = hotel.array[indexNumber!]

   }
}
```

Comment: It works beautifully. Now I know recognize my mistake. I was trying to obtain an array of arrays, instead the simple array to display. Thanks a lot.